# Matplotlib saving plot preferrences without the data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I am looking at saving a matplotlib plot of unknown state as it is user facing. The way that I am intending to do this is by taking the figure and putting the preferences into a dictionary. However this can be done by saving any base type into the dictionary and then utilizing the json library to save and load this dictionary to file.

The overall aim is to have OS independence and cross matplotlib version compatibility.

I've prototyped saving the preferences/settings of the plot to dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import json

def get_dict_from_fig(fig):
  fig_dict = {}

  axes_list = []
  for ax in fig.axes:
    axes_list.append(get_dict_for_axes(ax))
  fig_dict["Axes"] = axes_list

  fig_dict["Properties"] = get_dict_from_fig_properties(fig)
  return fig_dict

def get_dict_for_axes(ax):
  ax_dict = {}

  # Get the axis properties
  ax_dict["Properties"] = get_dict_from_axes_properties(ax)

  # Get lines from the axes and store it's data
  lines_list = []
  for index, line in enumerate(ax.lines):
    lines_list.append(get_dict_from_line(line, index))
  ax_dict["Lines"] = lines_list

  texts_list = []
  for text in ax.texts:
    texts_list.append(get_dict_from_text(text))
  ax_dict["Texts"] = texts_list

  ax_dict["Title"] = get_dict_from_text(ax.title)
  ax_dict["XAxis Title"] = get_dict_from_text(ax.xaxis.label)
  ax_dict["YAxis Title"] = get_dict_from_text(ax.yaxis.label)

  # Potentially need to handle artists that are Text
  artist_text_dict = {}
  for artist in ax.artists:
    if isinstance(artist, matplotlib.text.Text):
      artist_text_dict = get_dict_from_text(artist)
  ax_dict["Text from artists"] = artist_text_dict

  legend_dict = {}
  legend = ax.get_legend()
  if legend is not None and legend.get_visible():
    legend_dict = get_dict_from_legend(legend)
    legend_dict["Visible"] = True
  ax_dict["Legend"] = legend_dict

  return ax_dict

def get_dict_from_axes_properties(ax):
  prop_dict = {}
  prop_dict["Bounds"] = ax.get_position().bounds
  prop_dict["Dynamic"] = ax.get_navigate()
  prop_dict["Axison"] = ax.axison
  prop_dict["Frame On"] = ax.get_frame_on()
  prop_dict["XAxis Properties"] = get_dict_from_axis_properties(ax.xaxis)
  prop_dict["YAxis Properties"] = get_dict_from_axis_properties(ax.yaxis)

  # XAxis scale and Xlim
  prop_dict["XAxis Scale"] = ax.xaxis.get_scale()
  prop_dict["XLim"] = ax.get_xlim()
  # YAxis scale and Ylim
  prop_dict["YAxis Scale"] = ax.xaxis.get_scale()
  prop_dict["YLim"] = ax.get_ylim()

  return prop_dict

def get_dict_from_axis_properties(ax):
  prop_dict = {}
  label1On = ax._major_tick_kw.get('label1On', True)

  if isinstance(ax, matplotlib.axis.XAxis):
    if label1On:
      prop_dict["Position"] = "Bottom"
    else:
      prop_dict["Position"] = "Top"
  elif isinstance(ax, matplotlib.axis.YAxis):
    if label1On:
      prop_dict["Position"] = "Left"
    else:
      prop_dict["Position"] = "Right"
  else:
    raise ValueError("Value passed is not a valid axis")

  prop_dict["nTicks"] = len(ax.get_major_locator()())
  if isinstance(ax.get_major_locator(), ticker.FixedLocator):
    prop_dict["Tick Values"] = list(ax.get_major_locator())
  else:
    prop_dict["Tick Values"] = None

  formatter = ax.get_major_formatter()
  if isinstance(formatter, ticker.FixedFormatter):
    prop_dict["Tick Format"] = list(formatter.seq)
  else:
    prop_dict["Tick Format"] = ""

  labels = ax.get_ticklabels()
  if labels:
    prop_dict["Font size"] = labels[0].get_fontsize()
  else:
    prop_dict["Font size"] = ""

  prop_dict["Scale"] = ax.get_scale()
  prop_dict["Grid Style"] = get_dict_for_grid_style(ax)
  prop_dict["Visible"] = ax.get_visible()

  return prop_dict

def get_dict_for_grid_style(ax):
  grid_style = {}
  gridlines = ax.get_gridlines()
  if ax._gridOnMajor and len(gridlines) > 0:
    grid_style["Color"] = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(gridlines[0].get_color())
    grid_style["Alpha"] = gridlines[0].get_alpha()
    grid_style["Grid On"] = True
  else:
    grid_style["Grid On"] = False
  return grid_style

def get_dict_from_line(line, index=0):
  line_dict = {}
  line_dict["Line Index"] = index
  line_dict["Label"] = line.get_label()
  line_dict["Alpha"] = line.get_alpha()
  if line_dict["Alpha"] is None:
    line_dict["Alpha"] = 1
  line_dict["Color"] = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(line.get_color())
  line_dict["Linewidth"] = line.get_linewidth()
  line_dict["Line Style"] = line.get_linestyle()
  line_dict["Marker Style"] = get_dict_from_marker_style(line)
  return line_dict

def get_dict_from_marker_style(line):
  style_dict = {}
  style_dict["Face Color"] = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(line.get_markerfacecolor())
  style_dict["Edge Color"] = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(line.get_markeredgecolor())
  style_dict["Edge Width"] = line.get_markeredgewidth()
  style_dict["Marker Type"] = line.get_marker()
  style_dict["Marker Size"] = line.get_markersize()
  style_dict["ZOrder"] = line.get_zorder()
  return style_dict

def get_dict_from_text(text):
  text_dict = {}
  text_dict["Text"] = text.get_text()
  if text_dict["Text"]:
    text_dict["Transform"] = text.get_transform()
    text_dict["Position"] = text.get_position()
    text_dict["Style"] = get_dict_from_text_style(text)
  return text_dict

def get_dict_from_text_style(text):
  style_dict = {}
  style_dict["Alpha"] = text.get_alpha()
  if style_dict["Alpha"] is None:
    style_dict["Alpha"] = 1
  style_dict["Text Size"] = text.get_size()
  style_dict["Color"] = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(text.get_color())
  style_dict["hAlign"] = text.get_horizontalalignment()
  style_dict["vAlign"] = text.get_verticalalignment()
  style_dict["mAlign"] = text._multialignment
  style_dict["Rotation"] = text.get_rotation()
  style_dict["ZOrder"] = text.get_zorder()
  return style_dict

def get_dict_from_legend(legend):
  legend_dict = {}
  legend_elements_list = get_list_of_legend_children(legend)
  legend_elements_list.append(legend.legendPatch)

  text_list = []
  line_list = []
  for child in legend_elements_list:
    try:
      if isinstance(child, matplotlib.text.Text):
        if child.get_text() != None:
          text_list.append(get_dict_from_text(child))
      if isinstance(child, matplotlib.lines.Line2D):
        line_list.append(get_dict_from_line(child))
    except NotImplementedError:
      # Basically do nothing
      pass
      legend_dict["Text"] = text_list
      legend_dict["Line List"] =  line_list
      return legend_dict


def get_list_of_legend_children(legend):
  legend_list = []
  if hasattr(legend, 'get_children') and len(legend.get_children()) > 0:
    for child in legend.get_children():
      legend_list.append(get_list_of_legend_children(child))
  else:
    legend_list.append(legend)
  return legend_list

def get_dict_from_fig_properties(fig):
  fig_dict = {}
  fig_dict["Fig width"] = fig.get_figwidth()
  fig_dict["Fig height"] = fig.get_figheight()
  fig_dict["dpi"] = fig.dpi
  return fig_dict

XVals = np.array([1, 2, 3])
YVals = np.array([1, 2, 3])

plt.plot(XVals, YVals)
dictionary = get_dict_from_fig(plt.gcf())

f = open("./savefile.json", "w+")
f.write(json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4))
```

I was wondering if there was any way to do this already, perhaps with a maintained library? I've tried to find something to do it and nothing that I could find was overly useful, besides inspiration. I have already used mpld3 for inspiration.

I should probably have mentioned this earlier but when saving it is key to load back the data that has been saved, else there would be little point in saving it.

Comment: Concerning inspiration you can look through the [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io) source code, which needs to do something similar to recreate the plot. Also [plotly](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/modifying-a-matplotlib-figure/)'s `mpl_to_plotly` would need to do something similar. However, are you sure this isn't an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've looked through mpld3, let me edit the question to say so, I have yet to look through plotly however. With regards to it being an xyproblem, I have looked at many ways of saving things, for example pickling is an option but it isn't viable as cross platform it removes the ability for someone to copy and paste the end result to somewhere else, and have it work with different versions, I am open to changing my approach but this seems most viable.